# Javascript SessionStorage Items not available in first function call

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a javascript function in which whenever there is a change in a particular `select` 3 ajax Json calls are made and 3 `sessionStorage` items are populated which are used for creating dynamic dropdowns.

```js
// Update PayScales, Designations and Fields based on change in Organisation dropdown
        $(document).on('change', '#EmployeeDetails_OrganisationId', function () { getOrgDependentFields($(this).children(":selected").val(), true) });


// Fetch PayScales, Designations and Fields based on Organisation
function getOrgDependentFields(orgID, reformatTable) {
            if (sessionStorage.promotionCount && reformatTable) {
                    $('#promotionTable tbody').html("");
                    sessionStorage.removeItem('promotionCount');
                }
            if (orgID != "") {
                var url = '@Url.Action("GetOrganisationDependentInfo", "EmployeeData")?organisationId=' + orgID;
                $.getJSON(
                    url + '&infoType=level', function (data) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('levelJSON', JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                );
                $.getJSON(
                    url + '&infoType=payscale', function (data) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('payscaleJSON', JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                );
                $.getJSON(
                    url + '&infoType=designation', function (data) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('designationJSON', JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                );

            } else {
                sessionStorage.removeItem("levelJSON");
                sessionStorage.removeItem("payscaleJSON");
                sessionStorage.removeItem("designationJSON");
            }
        }
```

Now, this `select` input is pre-populated on page load and has a certain value.

I also have a button to dynamically add row to a table. When this button is clicked another method is invoked which checks if these `sessionStorage` items are set/available for generating the required dynamic HTML for the the table. If these are not, it in turn calls the `getOrgDependentFields` function and attempts to set them before using them to create the dynamic html row and appending it to the table

```js
//Add new row to Promotion table
        $("#addPromotion").click(function () {
            if (sessionStorage.promotionCount) {
                sessionStorage.promotionCount = Number(sessionStorage.promotionCount) + 1;
            } else {
                sessionStorage.promotionCount = @((Model.PromotionDetails == null) ? 0 : Model.PromotionDetails.Count());
            }
            var newPromotion = sessionStorage.promotionCount;
            var designationNames = '<option selected="selected" value="">Select Designation</option>';
            var levelNames = '<option selected="selected" value="">Select Level</option>';
            var payScaleNames = '<option selected="selected" value="">Select PayScale</option>';


          //Check if sessionStorage items are set and attempt to set them if NOT
           if (null == sessionStorage.getItem("designationJSON")) 
           {
         getOrgDependentFields($("#EmployeeDetails_OrganisationId").children(":selected").val(), false);

            }

            // Use the set sessionStorage items if they are set
            if (null != sessionStorage.getItem("designationJSON") && null != sessionStorage.getItem("levelJSON") && null != sessionStorage.getItem("payscaleJSON")) // Use the sessionStorage items if set 
            {
                var designationJSON = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("designationJSON"));
                designationJSON.forEach(function (designation) { designationNames += '<option value="' + designation.Id + '">' + designation.Name + '</option>'; });

                var levelJSON = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("levelJSON"));
                levelJSON.forEach(function (level) { levelNames += '<option value="' + level.Id + '">' + level.Name + '</option>'; });

                var payscaleJSON = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("payscaleJSON"));
                payscaleJSON.forEach(function (payscale) { payScaleNames += '<option value="' + payscale.Id + '">' + payscale.Name + '</option>'; });
            }
            // Bunch of other stuff to be done
        });
```

The issue I am facing is that when I click the button for the first time, the on click method is invoked and it hits the code portion to call the function `getOrgDependentFields` ( I have checked in debugger) and successfully traverses it, but when it encounters the code to check whether these `sessionStorage` items have been set, it seems them as null and doesn't enter the `if` block.

However, on the next click of the button, when it checks that whether the `sessionStorage` items are set, it is successfully able to see them and code proceeds normally and enters the next `if` block.

Apparently, the `sessionStorage` items are set/available after the execution completes for the first event

What could be the possible cause of this delay?

Comment: Is `sessionStorage`a javascript variable and what does this contains?

Comment: @reporter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I haven't used sessionStorage much, it might be a scope issue? 
Try localStorage, or a global/window level instead.

Comment: @Ryano I have tried doing the same. I have even switched browsers but the problem persists. As a workaround, I am currently calling the ```getOrgDependentFields ``` function on page load to pre-set these items. But that seems quite un-neccessary.

Comment: @sidz24x7 are you sure that the ajax request finish before you run the code that use the sessionStorage data? In the second event handler you call geOrgDependentFields and immediately tries to access the sessionData

Comment: @sney20002 You are right!! When I paused the code in debugger right after the line when the control returns to ```click``` handler function after completion from ```getOrgDependentFields ``` , I can see that all the 3 AJAX requests are still shown as pending.. Why is that so?? Shouldn't they complete before control returns to ```click``` handler function?? I even added a timeout after that line but the state changes to complete only after the ```click``` handler execution completes

Comment: @sney20002 Apparently the only way I can get this to work is I set ```async:false``` for the AJAX requests. This ensures they complete before proceeding to the next function. But I'm not sure that is a good idea :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery.when to know when all the request are completed.
Move the code that depends on the request to another function and in the event handler check if the request has been completed.

if the data exists run the function that render the rows immediately and if not run the requests and then the function that render the rows.

```
// Fetch PayScales, Designations and Fields based on Organisation
function getOrgDependentFields(orgID, reformatTable) {
    if (sessionStorage.promotionCount && reformatTable) {
        $('#promotionTable tbody').html("");
        sessionStorage.removeItem('promotionCount');
    }

    if (orgID != "") {
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetOrganisationDependentInfo", "EmployeeData")?organisationId=' + orgID;
        var request1 = $.getJSON(
            url + '&infoType=level', function (data) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('levelJSON', JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        );
        var request2 = $.getJSON(
            url + '&infoType=payscale', function (data) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('payscaleJSON', JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        );
        var request3 = $.getJSON(
            url + '&infoType=designation', function (data) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('designationJSON', JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        );

        return $.when(request1, request2, request3);
    } else {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("levelJSON");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("payscaleJSON");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("designationJSON");

        return $.Deferred().resolve();
    }
}

$("#addPromotion").click(function () {
  //Check if sessionStorage items are set and attempt to set them if NOT
  var dataExists = null != sessionStorage.getItem("designationJSON") &&
                      null != sessionStorage.getItem("levelJSON")
                      && null != sessionStorage.getItem("payscaleJSON");

    if (dataExists)
    {
        render();
    } else
    {
        getOrgDependentFields(
            $("#EmployeeDetails_OrganisationId").children(":selected").val(), false
        ).then(render);
    }
});

function render() {
    if (sessionStorage.promotionCount) {
        sessionStorage.promotionCount = Number(sessionStorage.promotionCount) + 1;
    } else {
        sessionStorage.promotionCount = @((Model.PromotionDetails == null) ? 0 : Model.PromotionDetails.Count());
    }

    var newPromotion = sessionStorage.promotionCount;
    var designationNames = '<option selected="selected" value="">Select Designation</option>';
    var levelNames = '<option selected="selected" value="">Select Level</option>';
    var payScaleNames = '<option selected="selected" value="">Select PayScale</option>';

    var designationJSON = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("designationJSON"));
    designationJSON.forEach(function (designation) { designationNames += '<option value="' + designation.Id + '">' + designation.Name + '</option>'; });

    var levelJSON = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("levelJSON"));
    levelJSON.forEach(function (level) { levelNames += '<option value="' + level.Id + '">' + level.Name + '</option>'; });

    var payscaleJSON = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("payscaleJSON"));
    payscaleJSON.forEach(function (payscale) { payScaleNames += '<option value="' + payscale.Id + '">' + payscale.Name + '</option>'; });

    // Bunch of other stuff to be done
}
```

The code can be simplified more if you use the json from the requests directly (only if you don't need the sessionStorage data for anything else)